# Прочитать весь std::cin в std::string

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, поток-ввода

Как прочитать весь текущий `std::cin` одной операцией в строку `std::string`?

Пробую так:

```
auto x = std::string{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin}, {}};
```

Но после копипаста куска текста при запуске программы она требует дальнейшего ввода.

Также я знаю количество строк, которое пользователь ввёл до текущего момента. Но итерироваться по всем строкам через `std::getline()` не подойдёт, надо именно 1 операцией все n строк прочитать в одну.

Comment: А что такое, по-вашему, **весь** `cin`? Вы же можете вводить информацию до бесконечности. Строка - понятно, ее конец - `\n`. А вы хотите ориентироваться - на что? Ладно, вот вам подсказака: в Windows Ctrl-Z закрывает стандартный поток ввода (в Linux это делает Ctrl-D, кажется).

Comment: @Harry всё, что ввели на момент выполнения указанного стэйтмэнта

Comment: @Harry с этими символами работает, но я не могу требовать от пользователей их вводить постоянно. В дебаге даже с ними не работает

Comment: @Harry дополнил вопрос

Comment: Т.е. если вызывается "стэйтмэнт", но вы не успели **ДО НЕГО** сделать нужный ввод - за какие-то наносекунды - то он должен просто вернуть пустую строку? Вот, вы делаете что-то типа: `cout<<"Enter data:"; стэйтмэнт;` - как вы предлагаете читать? Подсказка выведена, выполняется `стэйтмэнт` - но по факту на этот момент ничего введенного нет! А если ждать ввода пользователя - то какого именно? Сколько строк? Если точно знаете `n` - читайте и составляйте вместе `n` строк. Или - хотя это примерно то же самое, только в библиотеке - воспользуйтесь алгоритмом `copy_n`.

Comment: @Harry то есть 1 операцией n строк никак не прочитать?

Comment: Какой уровень грануляции, так сказать, вас интересует? Все равно сводится на нижнем уровне к чтению блока в буфер и его посимвольной передаче. У вас в приведенном вами коде происходит примерно то же самое. Если вы просто хотите делать это одним вызовом функции - то напишите ее и дело с концом. Хотите использовать стандартную - используйте `copy_n` с итератором потока. Не пойму, в чем необходимость именно одной операцией читать? В общем случае эти n строк могут превышать размеры всех буферов, так что все равно читаться будет в несколько низкоуровневых заходов...

Comment: @Harry меня производительность интересует. Если делать n раз `std::getline()` то в моём понимании это `>=n` дорогих операций чтения, а если 1 раз сделать операцию чтения большого блока, то так быстрее будет

Comment: @Harry если количество строк очень большое то читать максимально возможными блоками

Comment: Если интересует производительность, то не стоит использовать iostrem и читать / писать через стандартные потоки вообще

Comment: @VTT так а что надо использовать? n раз `scanf()`?

Comment: Платформенно-специфическое API для ввода-вывода.

Comment: @VTT а в рамках стандарта C++?

Comment: Ну тогда `getline`...

Comment: Производительность для `cin`, не для файлов? 8-0

Comment: С каких пор  std::getline() является дорогой операцией?..

Comment: это невозможно сделать в одну операцию нет

Comment: Можно одним [read()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) в достаточно большой буфер (конечно, результат будет не `std::string`)

Comment: @avp А какой размер указать в `read()`, если это n строк, а не байт?... И потом, у ТС не файл, а `cin`.

Comment: @Mikhailo, по поводу файлового дескриптора из cin [см. тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558447/retrieving-file-descriptor-from-a-stdfstream) (но лучше, конечно, сразу использовать `FILE *` (и Си)). С заданным количеством строк сложнее. Придется разбирать прочитанный буфер и возвращать излишек в поток  ugetc()-ом

Comment: @avp Я о том, что при считывании из cin, если это не перенаправление из файла, для чтения потребуется ввести все заказанное количество символов руками... `read` вроде же не останавливается при остановке ввода - или все читает, или до ошибки/конца файла? А `ungetc`, насколько я помню, гарантирует возврат только одного символа.

Comment: По крайней мере в GNU `ungetc()` позволяет "вернуть в поток" много символов (даже больше, чем было прочитано). А вот по поводу `read()`  из терминала я ошибся. В canon mode читает одну строку. Придется делать `ioctl(FIONREAD)` чтобы узнать количество доступных символов (см. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html)